# How to reboot Mac OS X into different OS other than the current one?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, reboot

I have 2 Mac OS X versions (10.5 and 10.6) installed on 2 different partition of my Mac. Is there a way that I can do from command line to reboot the system to switch to the other Mac OS X installation other than the current one?

Answer (score 8):

$ bless --mount /Volumes/MacPartitionX --setBoot;sudo shutdown -r now

I think that or something similar will work for your purposes.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose the startup volume for your Mac by holding down the option key (a.k.a. `alt`) as it boots up.

This selection is just a temporary choice and does not change the default that your Mac will use.

For more info:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1310

Comment: if you read question he want do it in command line

Answer (score 1):

See `man 8 bless`.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna change the disk by:
Turn on, or restart, your Mac.
Immediately press and hold the Option key. After a few seconds, the Startup Manager should appear. The Startup Manager scans for available volumes. Select yours and hit enter to boot to that.
Then shutdown, or restart and repeat above to switch.